# Parse and extract after '=' in a string in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say my url atm is

```
http://test.com/?city=toronto
```

I'm able to get the requestURL string that is

```
/?city=toronto
```

From here, I was wondering if there is a built in function or a standard procedure of extracting the word "toronto" or any other word that comes after the `=` from the string.

Answer (score 4):

A standard procedure (as you mentioned) of doing this, you can get all the parameter values including value of city or any other parameter you may add to it.

```
var values = new URL('http://test.com/?city=toronto').searchParams.values();
for(var value of values){
    console.log(value);
}
```

**UPDATE**

As @taystack mentioned in the comment, if you only want the value of a specific parameter (city) in this case, you can use:

```
new URL('http://test.com/?city=toronto').searchParams.get('city');
```

Comment: `new URL('http://test.com/?city=toronto').searchParams.get("city")` will do the job as well.

Comment: Sure it will. Thanks for adding this.

Answer (score 0):

Use split();

```
var url = '/?city=toronto'.split('=');
console.log(url[1]);
```

Comment: A query like, `/?city=toronto&search=burgers` might break this.

Comment: you get an array with another split with & in this case but you have to take care of the indexing

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has a new module called [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html), which encodes the semantics of a url string. You don’t need to do any string manipulation.

```
const URL = require('url')
let my_url = new URL('http://test.com/?city=toronto')
```

URL#search returns the string representing the search:

```
my_url.search // '?city=toronto'
```

URL#query returns the search string excluding `?`:

```
my_url.query // 'city=toronto'
```

and URL#searchParams returns an object encoding the search string:

```
my_url.searchParams // something kind of like {'city':'toronto'}
my_url.searchParams.get('city') // 'toronto'
my_url.searchParams.keys() // ['city'] (all the keys)
my_url.searchParams.values() // ['toronto'] (all the values)
```